# how to serve files from /tmp directory in django

Tags: django

I want to serve downloadable files located in the /tmp directory via django.  However I don't want these files copied or moved to the static_dir.  The whole point of having the files in /tmp is that a cronjob will delete them every night.

I realized I could just set /tmp as my static_dir in the django settings, but I already have a static_dir set that I am using in my project.

My question is what is the easiest way to allow an end user to download files located in the /tmp directory?

If I hit this url:
http://localhost:8000/api/v2/tmp/testfile.zip

I would expect to download /tmp/testfile.zip

Can this be done via just a single entry in urls.py?  Or am I going to have to create a new view?

Comment: Please don't. This is quite unsafe. What if someone aims to download `http://localhost:8000/api/v2/path/to/secret.file`? One could for example aim to download files that contain (parts of) your database, or your operating system, and for example use this to access sensitive information, or login with server credentials.

Comment: Note that in production, Django does *not* serve static files (at all). Then you need to set nginx/apache to handle this, exactly because the idea is that you store static files, etc. on a safe place.

Comment: Oh okay so this is really more of an nginx question then?

Comment: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/serving-static-content/, but as Willem already explained chose proper folder as /tmp is not considered safe to host